# Creating a SOAP Request with ASP.Net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, soap, request

I am talking to a technical contact at the Server Website who expects me to be using Visual Studio while I just want to hand write script. See below for the SOAP request I need to generate. (I have replaced the actual URL with a dummy one) . I am pretty new to ASP and SOAP as you might guess and I have tried to Google an example script.

```
POST /PropertySearchService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: portal.someurl.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetBranches xmlns="http://portal.someurl.com">
      <strClientID>string</strClientID>
    </GetBranches>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am talking to a technical contact at
>   the Server Website who expects me to
>   be using Visual Studio while I just
>   want to hand write script

You should get over that. You're not working with Classic ASP here.

Don't Google it. You won't find any good examples of sending SOAP messages because all the good examples let .NET build the message for them. Use "Add Web Reference" and specify the URL that your contact is probably trying to give you. It will produce a proxy class that you can call.

See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!790.entry). It's not 100% like your case, but it's close enough to give you an idea of the right way to do these things.

Comment: John,
Downloaded Virtual Studio 2008 trial version and eventually struggled my way through it

Comment: Great! Congratulations! Hope to be seeing you in here more often.